# What is this bean-like plant in a forest on Vancouver Island, British Columbia?

Tags: identification, beans, peas

I found a plant near my house in Malahat on Vancouver Island, British Columbia. It seems to be some sort of bean.

It is a vine and has pods that are about an inch long and the seeds are about 2 mm across; they are brown with tiny black spots.

[image: picture of the bean or pea]

Could anyone identify it for me?

Comment: Do you have photographs of the plant as well? If you have them, the whole plant as well as close-ups of the leaves, flowers and pods. Thanks!

Comment: i would have to wait until the sun came up to get a good pic but i'm sure of what is is as i have remembered what it looked like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out what it is.

This seed is from the field pea plant.

[image: field pea]

[image: field pea plant]

The place i found it says:

> Seeds are spherical, up to 5 mm in diameter, with thin, tuberculate seed coat, dark brown, sometimes with dark spots."

Comment: Wow, love to see if you are right...that was tough to find!!  I am impressed...

Comment: I found the pods and seeds on a plant so i could tell